# Word for a change that only applies once

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to remember the word for a function that can be applied multiple times to the same data set but only makes its change once. I've got a Rails migration that sets some data, but only if that data isn't set. So if it is run multiple times it only does work once.

Comment: This seems like a perfect question for english.stackexchange.com.  Of course, you already have your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you thinking about the word "idempotent"? (I'm frantically looking for my Category Theory book ...)

Comment: Thats the word! Thanks so much. Now I can complete my commit message :)